# How do I connect my docker to remote database?

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, spring-boot

I want to access mongo db running on url: "xyz" (remote host), and in my spring boot application properties, I have mentioned the mongodb url to "xyz".
Now when i run this application inside a docker container, it can not connect to remote url, and shows the connection refused error. 
How do We access the remote database from inside a container ?

Below is my DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
EXPOSE 8090
COPY target/<jar file> /application.jar
RUN mkdir /logs
RUN /bin/sh -c "apk add --no-cache bash"
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
CMD ["-DLOG_DIR=/logs", "-DLOG_FILE=application.log", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=local", "-Xmx1g", "/application.jar", "&"]
```

My Application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = <mongodb-url>
```

I build my docker image as:

```
docker build -t app:app .
```

I run the docker image as:

```
docker run -d <imageId>
```

Comment: did you set network settings for your docker environment, if not you should.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MuratGüvenç updated the question. Please let me know what network setting I have to do ?

Comment: @AlexKarshin updated

Comment: Where is the MongoDB and what is the host within the spring.data.mongodb.uri?

Comment: @Indivon mongodb host is accessible when i run the application directly on docker host, without running inside the docker container. Mongodb host is not same as docker host. Cant share the host details, as it is a private host.

Comment: I asked because DNS and reachable IPs (subnet) are different within a docker container. However, did you check that the host of the Mongo is reachable from the inside of the container? E.g. by `docker exec -ti <container-name> ping <host-of-mongo>` ?

Comment: @Indivon yes host is reachable. But when i run the service i get connection refused. Also when i try to login mongo using --host <host ip> argument it says  host not reachable.

Comment: Then, I guess it's a problem of the host that runs mongo. You could check the `bindIP` in `mongod.conf` (e.g. if it is bound to localhost/127.0.0.1 or only a local LAN 192.168.1.123), because the container is in another network. Another option could be the firewall, which prevents any connections from "outside"!. You can also test that by running the docker container within the host's network (using `--network host`).

Answer (score 2):

Following command gets the job done.

```
docker run --net=host <imageId>
```

Be careful with this command because `--net=host` makes the container share network with the host. The network of the container will no longer be isolated.